# launching java applications in a cross platform way

Tags: java, deployment, installation, desktop-application

I have a Java program, let's say it's called MyApp.jar

To run it on Linux, I just write a shell script called myapp.sh, which simply runs `java -jar MyApp.jar` and double click on it. Everything works well.

On Windows 7, I cannot assume that the `java` command will be in everyone's path (if that's what you call it on Windows), so I have to have a workaround and do something like create a batch script with this in it: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar MyApp.jar`, which is obviously a Bad Solution... and it doesn't work on XP or Vista. It works on *most* Windows 7 machines though.

My application ships as a .zip file, the user extracts it to a folder MyApp, and then ideally will double click on *something* to invoke the program. So far it has a .sh script for Linux users to double click on, and a batch script for Windows 7 users (it works in *most* cases). It creates and consumes files in its own directory (MyApp).

What is the best way to invoke this program in a cross platform way?

Thanks!

Comment: The most standard way of doing it is probably Java WebStart.

Comment: @biziclop  I think you should have added a few more words to the comment and made it an answer.  I did, in any case.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I know but that's all I had time and energy for. It's getting late here. :)

Comment: In all versions of Windows, Oracle installs `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` into the system directory, so it would be in `%PATH%`. So if JRE is installed, you can run `java.exe` or `javaw.exe` without path. I'm not sure this works as expected with 32-bit JRE on 64-bit OS. Anyway, *Java Web Start* is the most convenient way to deploy Java applications; additionally it has auto-update feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't deliver Java with your application, it might be a good solution to use JAVA_HOME to start it. It is set on, well... not all but many systems.
Definitly you should not use C:\Program Files (x86)... it is much better to use the environment variable %ProgramFiles%

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by biziclop, [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) is commonly used to install/launch/update Java desktop apps.

As far as the JRE goes, it is usually sufficient to use the `deployJava.js` linked from that page above to ensure minimum necessary JRE is installed, and the elements in the JNLP file to specify any JRE micro-versions that are supported for the app.

#### Application launch

JWS can install desktop shortcuts and menu items when supported by the OS.  Those can be specified in the launch file, or added/removed at run-time using services of the JNLP API.

Answer (score 1):

Java application require a java runtime environment with a certain version to be installed on the target system.

The most convenient way, to my opinion, is to ship all libraries and documentation in a single archive and add start scripts for windows and *nix systems.

You could ship a JRE with your application too but then you'd have to support builds for different platforms...